# fuseki 2.0.0 update seems not working

Tags: insert-update, fuseki

i'm trying to update fuseki using this update request which is sent to http://localhost:3030/test/update :

```
DELETE    { <http://example.org/resource/user38702668>   <http://example.org/follower> ?a } INSERT{<http://example.org/resource/user38702668> <http://example.org/follower> <http://localhost/1212>} where{<http://example.org/resource/user38702668> <http://example.org/follower> ?a}
```

the fuseki webinterface returns

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Success</h1>
<p>
Update succeeded
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

but when i query http://localhost:3030/test/update, i still have the original triple (i.e., not the updated one with value http://localhost:3030/test/update ) in fuseki. any thought?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but I had the same exact issue.

The problem is that Fuseki is quite sensitive towards the graphs. It needs to know which graph you want to remove your triples from, or it will look only in the default graph. So the response that it gives you (200, OK) is actually right because it couldn't find the triples to remove them and as such it worked! So if you change your query to something like:

```
with <graph_URL_here>
DELETE    
{ 
    <http://example.org/resource/user38702668>   <http://example.org/follower> ?a 
} 
INSERT
{
    <http://example.org/resource/user38702668> <http://example.org/follower> <http://localhost/1212>
} 
where{
    <http://example.org/resource/user38702668> <http://example.org/follower> ?a
}
```